# Storing Date into mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql

```
// some code
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$datetime = new DateTime("now");

// result: 4th October, 2014. 3:35 PM
$datetime->format("jS F, Y. g:i A");
```

---

```
$value    = $_POST['Cfname'];
$value2   = $_POST['Csubject'];
$value3   = $_POST['Cemail'];
$value4   = $_POST['Cmessage'];
$datetime = $_POST['Ctime'];

$sql = "
    INSERT INTO query
        (Cfname, Csubject, Cemail, Cmessage, Ctime) 
    VALUES 
        ('$value', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$datetime')
";
```

When the form is submitted, everything works fine but the date column, It gets stored as `0000-00-00`  instead of format I specified and getting error as: *Undefined index: **Ctime***

I am a newbie in `PHP` and `MySQL` and I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: try to see exactly what is inside $_POST['Ctime'] using an echo or var_dump

Comment: What you are trying to do is not going to work. I would suggest edit the date column in your database to a varchar. the date is used to to store a date like: `date('Y-m-d')` in you database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which input type are you using in your form for the date? The date column will only accept a value of Y-m-d which would be 2014-10-4 for today. If you're using `type="date"`, it should work right out of the box.

index.php:

```
<?php
$datetime = new DateTime();
?>

<form action="insertSql.php" method="POST">
    <input name="Ctime" type="date" value="<?php echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d') ?>">
</form>
```

You only have to put `value="<?php echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d') ?>"` if you want the default date to be today.

---

insertSql.php:

```
<?php
$datetime = $_POST['Ctime'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO query (Ctime) VALUES ('$datetime')";
?>
```

---

You can use a varchar column if you want to input the date like 4th October 2014, but just know that it won't sort correctly in your database by date if you're using varchar.

Answer (score 0):

```
date('Y-m-d',time())
```

is probably what you want;